# java.io.EOFException when reading from Python Client

Tags: java, python, sockets

I am experimenting with a server-client connection using both Java and Python. I have used Java for the server and Python for the client. Sending data from the server to the client works fine, but when I attempt to send data from the client to the server, it throws an EOFException. What am I doing wrong here?

Server code:

```java
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class JavaFile {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            ServerSocket serversocket = new ServerSocket(6000);
            Socket socket = serversocket.accept();
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            output.writeUTF("Hello Client!");
            String s = (String)input.readUTF();
            System.out.println(s);

            serversocket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 6000
s.connect((host, port))

message = s.recv(1024)
print(message.decode())
s.send("Hello Server!".encode())
s.close()
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Note that readUTF()/writeUTF doesn't read/write Strings directly. You eould need a `Reader`/`Writer` (or `Scanner`) for this.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8